# ¿Cómo paso argumentos de una actividad/ventana a otra con un log in en AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy nuevo en desarrollo con Android y tengo un problema al pasar argumentos de una ventana a otra (obviando también las sentencias de importación y los paquetes). Aquí va el código de la clase principal:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Variables/Campos de la clase
    private TextView miUsuario;   //Objeto TextView correspondiente a la "caja" de texto del usuario
    private TextView miMens;   //TexView de la advertencia de "user y/o pass incorrectos"
    private EditText miPass;   //Objeto EditText correspondiente a la "caja" de texto de la contraseña
    private Button btnVerificar;
    private Intent miIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //CASTEO XML A JAVA MEDIANTE LA CLASE R
        miUsuario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plntxtUsuario);
        miPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plntxtPass);
        miMens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMens);
        btnVerificar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVerificar);
        btnVerificar.setOnClickListener(this);   //Añadimos el escuchador al botón

        //Ponemos el mensaje de error invisible
        miMens.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    //Invalidamos el método onClick
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String user = "root",contr = "rootroot";
        String nombre = miUsuario.getText().toString();   //Guardamos el texto de la caja del usuario
        String password = miPass.getText().toString();   //Guardamos el texto de la caja del password
        if(v.getId() == (R.id.btnVerificar)) {   //Si el boton ha sido pulsado
            //Verificamos el log in
            if (((nombre).equals(user)) && ((password).equals(contr))) {
                //Pasamos a la siguiente pantalla de bienvenida
                miIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ventana2.class);   //Llamamos al constructor de la clase Ventana2
                miIntent.putExtra("nom_user", nombre);   //Colocamos valores dentro del intent mediante un array clave-valor
                miIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   //Deja On Top la nueva ventana
                startActivity(miIntent);   //Fuerza la apertura de la actividad abriendo la ventana
            } else {
                miUsuario.setText("");   //Reseteamos los campos de usuario y pass
                miPass.setText("");
                miMens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y la segunda ventana (Ventana2,obviando también las sentencias de importación y los paquetes):

```
public class Ventana2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables/Campos de la clase
    private TextView miTextView;   //TextView de la frase "Bienvenido al sistema "
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ventana2);

        //Recupero el intent que abrió esta ventana/actividad
        intent = getIntent();
        //Chequeo si trae parámetros
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        //CASTEO DE OBJETOS XML A JAVA
        miTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBienv);

        //Chequeamos si bundle trae o no los parámetros de intent
        if(bundle != null){
            miTextView.setText((miTextView.getText().toString()) + "" + bundle.getString("nom_user"));
            miTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            miTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }
}
```

Y cuando el log in es correcto, solo ejecuta la primera parte del onCreate de la clase Ventana2, es decir, o no pasa correctamente el argumento del usuario o no lo recibe bien.
Además, al hacer click en el botón, ejecuta un Toast.makeText de la nada imprimiendo la contraseña introducida y no sé el por qué.
¡¡¡Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: Hola Jesus no se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, "Y cuando el log in es correcto, solo ejecuta la primera parte del onCreate de la clase Ventana2", en realidad no estas realizando un Intent, no hay forma de abrir Ventana2, Te sugiero revisar el código si es en realidad el que tiene este comportamiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cambia en el intent para llamar a la Ventana2 el contexto que manejas por:

```
miIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ventana2.class);
miIntent.putExtra("nom_user", nombre);
miIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(miIntent);
```

Y en Ventana2 recibe el parámetro en un `String` directamente

```
String nombre = getIntent().getExtras.getString("nom_user");
```

Espero te sirva.